# Error in applying patch in Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, patch-management

Recently i have installing apache 2.2.21 from the source for testing purpose.
After doing clean installation of apache i want to patch it with the patches provided here: http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/patches/

Anyway when i put the patch command as mention in the page it show this result:

> File to patch: CVE-2011-3368.patch
>   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file CVE-2011-3368.patch.rej

Is there something wrong with my patch?If not,how could i verified that the patch has been implemented or not?

Comment: Have you tried reading the patch and related files?

Comment: yeah,i had read the documentation but still not quite understand on how the patch works.

Comment: I already solved the problems! Actually after checking through the patches it contain the path that it will change.After moving the patches to the designated path, i run the patch command:

patch -s < CVE-2011-3368.patch

and it works!

Comment: Hi - welcome to Server Fault. It's not necessary to add "Solved" to your title. When you can add your own answer and then accept that to show that the problem is solved. In the meantime your comment should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

This [problem was solved](https://serverfault.com/questions/373723/error-in-applying-patch-in-apache#comment381510_373723) by moving the patches to the correct location before running the command

```
patch -s < CVE-2011-3368.patch
```